# Zend: class not found?

Tags: zend-framework, deployment

It's the first time I'm trying to deploy a ZF application on a server.

The problem I'm getting is that it doesn't seem to be able to find a class I've created. Here's the error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Form_Installation_Admin' not found in /home/mingos/public_html/bugraid/application/modules/installation/controllers/IndexController.php on line 46
```

`Form_Installation_Admin` can be found in `/application/forms/installation/Admin.php` and it works on my local server (ie, all the classes are found with no problems). However, on the shared host, it appears that the application doesn't quite know how to resolve the locations of my apps. The same is true for all the forms in subdirectories of `/forms/`, but does not happen to the forms placed directly in the `/forms/` directory and named `Form_FormName`.

What could be the cause and how to fix this (apart from placing all forms in the `/forms/` dir)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, hate to answer my own question, but the answer was rather trivial.

My local server runs on Windows. Windows seems to be case-insensitive when parsing the class name. My hosted account is on a server running on Linux, which is case sensitive. Renaming the `/forms/installation` directory to `/folder/Installation` did the trick.